# Spring singleton-scoped bean has different propeties values for different objects

Tags: java, spring

My app is built upon Spring + SockJs. Main page represents a table of available connections so that user can monitor them in real-time. Every single url monitor can be suspended/resumed separatelly from each other. The problem is once you suspend some monitor then you can never resume it back because ApplicationEvents property of MonitoringFacade bean suddenly becomes null for the SINGLE entity. For other entites listener keeps working pretty well. When attempt to invoke methods of such null listener NullPointerException is never thrown though.

```
class IndexController implements ApplicationEvents
...
public IndexController(SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate, MonitoringFacade monitoringFacade) {
        this.simpMessagingTemplate = simpMessagingTemplate;
        this.monitoringFacade = monitoringFacade;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug(">>Index controller initialization.");
        }

        monitoringFacade.addDispatcher(this);
    }

...

@Override
    public void monitorUpdated(String monitorId) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug(">>Sending monitoring data to client with monitor id " + monitorId);
        }

        try {
            ConfigurationDTO config = monitoringFacade.findConfig(monitorId);
            Report report = monitoringFacade.findReport(monitorId);
            ReportReadModel readModel = ReportReadModel.mapFrom(config, report);
            simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/client/update", readModel);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.ERROR, "Exception: ", e);
        }
    }

public class MonitoringFacadeImpl implements MonitoringFacade
...
private ApplicationEvents dispatcher;

  public void addDispatcher(ApplicationEvents dispatcher) {
        logger.info("Setting up dispatcher");
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

...
 @Override
    public void refreshed(RefreshEvent event) {
        final String monitorId = event.getId().getIdentity();
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug(String.format(">>Refreshing monitoring data with monitor id '%s'", monitorId));
        }

        Configuration refreshedConfig = configurationService.find(monitorId);
        reportingService.compileReport(refreshedConfig, event.getData());

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug(String.format(">>Notifying monitoring data updated with monitor id '%s'", monitorId) + dispatcher);
        }
        dispatcher.monitorUpdated(monitorId); // here dispatcher has null value... or it's actually not

    }
```

void refreshed(RefreshEvent event) method succesfully receives updates from Quartz scheduler through the interface and sends it back to controller.

The question is how a singleton-scoped bean can have different property values for different objects it is applied for and why such a property becomes null even though i have never set it to null?

UPD:

```
@MessageMapping("/monitor/{monitorId}/suspend")
    public void handleSuspend(@DestinationVariable String monitorId) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug(">>>Handling suspend request for monitor with id " + monitorId);
        }

        try {
            monitoringFacade.disableUrlMonitoring(monitorId);
            monitorUpdated(monitorId);// force client update
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.ERROR, "Exception: ", e);
        }
    }

    @MessageMapping("/monitor/{monitorId}/resume")
    public void handleResume(@DestinationVariable String monitorId) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug(">>>Handling resume request for monitor with id " + monitorId);
        }

        try {
            monitoringFacade.enableUrlMonitoring(monitorId);
            monitorUpdated(monitorId);// force client update
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.ERROR, "Exception: ", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You seem to have omitted annotations present on some of your fields and methods, whereas Spring (unless using XML configuration) is quite dependent on proper annotation configuration. Is your `IndexController` some kind of `@Controller`? Is your dispatcher `@Autowired` somewhere? Is `MonitoringFacadeImpl` defined as a Spring-managed bean somewhere in your configuration?

Comment: 1) Yes, me controller is annotated with Controller 
2) When autowiring i get circular reference so i set is via PostConstruct in controller 
3) Yes, everything is configured via annotations. My IDE tells me if something goes wrong with configs.

Comment: Can you please add code where you resume/suspend your monitor and also the NullPointer stack trace.

Comment: @Raghvendra Garg
Sure, updated question. And is there no NullPointerException exception stacktrace. my logger tells me there is null but nothing happens when trying to access on null.